# PayPal Payouts with encoded user id

Tags: paypal

I need some help with Paypal Payouts. I am currently using Java SDK and working in sandbox environment.

I am trying to implement a button in my webapp that will enable users to receive monetary awards in their paypal accounts. My first idea was to ask for their email and then - using the SDK create a payout item and send that. All works well, except that when someone types (unintentionally I assume) wrong email, then money are not going to be transferred. That is why I decided that asking the user to login with paypal and then using their paypal id will be much more error-proof.

So I followed the steps described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/).

I am successfully able to exchange the authorization code and receive access and refresh tokens. Then I use those to load user info that contains only `user_id` (login scope is `openid`).

When I try to create a `PayoutItem` with recipient type `PAYPAL_ID` and value - `user_id` from `Userinfo` object - the operation is unsuccessful (no error - just the batch result is `null`).

We do not have and we do not expect to have any transactions from this user - so there is no way to use `getTransactionDetails` in order to retrieve payer id.

I suspect that `user_id` is not the correct property to use. However, I cannot find any information on how I can integrate payouts with recipient type `PAYPAL_ID` combined with paypal login.

Help, please!